# Mounting LED strip to a desk setup

Tags: led, desk, cable-management

I'm planning on adding on a LED lighting to my desk setup to get a nice, smooth glow behind the monitor on a wall. So the plan is to mount an LED strip on the back edge of the desk so that it lightens the wall next to it. But i have 2 concerns / questions. Could you help me out?

- I have some cables hanging over the back edge of the desk. Wouldn't the LEDs damage them? I was thinking i could always try to set the cables in between the particular diodes, but it's a concern nonetheless.
- I want a nice smooth glow with a soft gradient. Is the LED strip good enough to do that, or do i need to put it in a tube mount covered with a semitransparent bar to blur it out a little bit?

Comment: How far from the LED strips to the wall?

Comment: Quite close, about 4.2 cm (1.65"). But i can still move it away a bit if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The led strip won't damage your wires. If anything, it's that loose wires/stuff can damage the led strip.

To that end, you might choose an led strip that's encapsulated in silicone. These are usually sold as outdoor/waterproof.

To get very smooth light (no hotspots), opt for a COB led strip. The light from those doesn't look like discrete dots. Having said that, a regular strip firing back toward the wall won't be terrible for hotspots.